# A SO question I liked has vanished, how do I find out what happened to it?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

I realize it was a [subjective poll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224867/what-programming-language-do-you-wish-would-quietly-retire), but I liked it and now it's vanished. I feel kind of robbed, like if someone had deleted the comic question or the orders of magnitude question.

How do I find out who did it, what their rationalization was and where they live (that last one is a joke).

P.S. Its [partner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337/what-programming-language-do-you-wish-would-catch-on) is still around.

Comment: The question has been deleted. It's still viewable if you've got > 10K rep, but you'd need the link as it won't come up in any search.

Comment: http://74.125.113.132/search?q=cache:IPS8rWNuqjAJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/224867/what-programming-language-do-you-wish-would-quietly-retire+what-programming-language-do-you-wish-would-quietly-retire&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=firefox-a

Comment: @Lady - all right, any normal search of the site.

Comment: it did show up in searches, that's how I got the links

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I liked that one too, so I undeleted it.

Comment: "It's good to be the king."

Comment: "We don't run Stack Overflow. The community does." - bah

Comment: @Downvoter: We're all equal here, be it users, 10K users, moderators, or Jeff. Jeff's a little **more** equal, though.

Comment: it appears to have been deleted again

Answer (score 1):

```
closed by Jeff Atwood♦ Jan 20 at 23:21

deleted by SilentGhost, gnovice, KennyTM Mar 3 at 19:24
```

It was deleted. 10K users may vote to delete closed posts. 10K users can also vote to undelete.